# I can't enqueue my scripts - They literally aren't being added to my site

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, scripts

Ok, I've literally copy-pasted different enqueueing code from about 5 different sources (Including wordpress), and not a single one works.

Here's the code I'm using in functions.php:

```
<?php

function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script(
        'main',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('main');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );

?>
```

and it literally does nothing. No scripts added into my HTML. nothing.

This is my first time using wordpress, and nobody has explained the functions file to me completely right, but from my understanding, i don't do anything like  do I?

I've also put `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` right before `</body>` if that means anything.

EDIT:
**I've solved the problem**

Stupidly, I'd forgotten to add `<?php wp_head(); ?>` right before `</head>`, this screwed it all up. I also changed the 'main' identifier to something more unique, which didn't change anything but might be a better practice anyway.

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins activated? Can you disable all plugins? Can you try the default theme? Can you try a different hook than `main` as it could already be in use?

Comment: 'Do you have any caching plugins activated?' - No
'Can you disable all plugins?' - I just did it then, no fix :(
'Can you try the default theme?' - How do I do this and would it help?
'Can you try a different hook than main as it could already be in use?' - I just tried that then, no luck.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer. That is still most appropriate way, even if you resolved it yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

The codex suggests using the function `get_stylesheet_directory()` in this instance as the `get_template_directory_uri()` can get overriden by child themes.

- [get_template_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)
- [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

In my experience WordPress can sometimes provide 2 or 3 similar functions.

Comment: I've tried:

get_template_directory_uri()
get_stylesheet_directory()
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

...and none of them made any difference

Comment: What about [get_template_directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)?

Comment: I've solved the issue. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() was in fact the correct syntax in this situation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a problem! If this answer helped, can you accept it. If not, post your own answer outlining the steps you took to resolve the issue and accept that.

Answer (score -1):

You should register js file. Please read WordPress codex

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script